# Visual Studio Web Form Application Loading Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have recently attempted to begin learning C# and ASP.NET.  I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and tried to follow along with a few tutorials on creating a Web Form Application.  Unfortunately, when I create a new web form application project, the Visual Studio screen and Solution explorer do not load as other Youtube tutorials and my books indicate they should.

- When I "Save All", I am not getting the Form1.cs, Program.cs, or Form1.Designer.cs files to be created.
- Also, I do not get the Form1.CS window appearing so I can drag objects from the toolbox into the form.  Instead I just get a default.aspx tab with code.

I have posted a quick video illustrating this on YouTube to describe this in greater detail.  Am I doing something wrong, or could it be that my Visual Studio is not working properly?  I had Visual Studio 2010 installed before this, but tried to uninstall it and install 2012.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXkcCnmHnk

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the Web Developer plugin for web apps?

Comment: You are creating the wrong project type.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded and installed the "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web" software from the Microsoft site (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-web).  This starts the download with Microsoft Web Platform Installer for "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web with Windows Azure SDK (Latest)" and then it says that I already have it installed.  Is there anything else I would need to install with this to make it function properly?

Comment: error ,solution and many option here in view menu bar....just click and show your right side pane.......

Comment: I found another tutorial on Youtube that seems to work like my books are recommending. You can see how his Visual Studio is functioning differently than my video shows:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOPM3jFo-qQ&noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at tutorials for Winform and for that you need to get
 [Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop)

Comment: That may be the case.  I am in the process of downloading Visual Studio Express 2012 for desktop and will try to repeat the steps in my book and in the other videos I've seen.  I will keep you posted once that is completed.  Sorry if this seems like a really basic question, but I've been struggling with this for a few days and am still struggling to make distinctions between the different Visual Studios and how the ASP.NET platform all comes together.  This has been more challenging than I anticipated, but appreciate everyone's insight and support.